# How to use the Integral test for convergence on finite domains ($\int_0^{1} cot(\frac{\pi x}{4}) dx$)?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

When using The Integral test for convergence on infinite domains $\int_a^{\infty} f(x)dx$ , the [Integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) is defined as  (*assuming $f(x),g(x)$ are non-negative*)

**$ \lim \limits_{ x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$**

My Question is as follows , When using the test on finite domains such as
$\int_0^{1} cot(\frac{\pi x}{4}) dx$ and choosing $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ ,

Does the test look like :

**Option 1 :** $ \lim \limits_{ x \to 1} \frac{cot(\frac{\pi x}{4})}{\frac{1}{x}}$

or

**Option 2 :** $ \lim \limits_{ x \to 0} \frac{cot(\frac{\pi x}{4})}{\frac{1}{x}}$

Given the test for improper integrals behaves is defined as **$ \lim \limits_{ x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$** and $\int_a^{\infty} f(x)dx$  can written as $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty}\int_a^{x} f(x)dx$ I thought only ***option 1*** is the right choice ,

however using the above test for the integral won't help and only by using $ \lim \limits_{ x \to 0} \frac{cot(\frac{\pi x}{4})}{\frac{1}{x}}$ (**Option 2**) the test works .

**How do I decide which domain is the limit in the Integral test ?**

Comment: I have never seen this test before, what is $g$ here? Surely you can't just pick an arbitrary function?

Comment: $g(x)=\frac{1}{x} $ is non-negative in $(0,1)$  We were taught this test in class , I linked a wiki page for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I see there is some general misundestanding. The idea is to use a "$\textit{easy}$" function $g$. What you are doing is an asymptotic estimation of the integral function, so first of all you should seek where does your function diverge for $x$ in the integral domain. Hence, in your example as $\cot x$ divergese around $k\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have a divergence problem in the inferior extreme i.e. $0$.

Now, as I was saying, the choice of $g$ is not random, you are not picking any function you desire, you are picking $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^n}$ for a suited $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and check what happens to the limit:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)}{\frac{1}{x^n}}$$
where $f(x)$ is the integral function. Notice it is an indecision form of the kind $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.
What you are left with is to understand for which $n$ this limit is finite, or in other words for which $n$: $f(x)\sim\frac{1}{x^n}$ in a neighborhood of $0$. If $n<1$ it means you have convergence, otherwise (as in this case) divergence.

Comment: What do you mean by the term "function diverges..."? I think the idea in your answer is correct,  but it is important to be rigorous.